# Keras weight amount error

Tags: python, keras, lstm

Currently, I was working on the lstm that generates text based on the Alice in Wonderland story. I have two scripts,  [training script](https://github.com/kir486680/Alice-LSTM/blob/master/alice.py) and [testing script](https://github.com/kir486680/Alice-LSTM/blob/master/test.py). For each epoch, I decided to create its own file with weights you can see all files that were created [here](https://github.com/kir486680/Alice-LSTM). Training script works perfectly, it creates all files and has no errors during the execution. When I run my testing script, it compiles but during the execution, gives me an error

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 2 layers into a model with 3 layers.
```

I created completely the same architecture for both networks and I cant find the problem.
I googled and found that it works. I changed my version of keras to 2.0.2 and it worked but how can I change my code, so it can run on the latest version of keras?

Comment: My rep is less than 15, but you can help me.

Comment: Then just accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer (of course, if it has resolved your issue) to mark it as answered. I think you will get rep after accepting the answer (then you can upvote it if you want).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are saving the whole model (architecture + weights + etc.) the way you are calling `ModelCheckpoint`. According to [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint), `ModelCheckpoint` takes an argument called `save_weights_only` with default value of `False` such that:

> if True, then only the model's weights will be saved
>   (`model.save_weights(filepath)`), else the full model is saved
>   (`model.save(filepath)`).

So, in your code, you are saving the whole model since you are not setting the `save_weights_only=True`. You can either load your model using [`keras.model.load_model()`](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) or you can set `save_weights_only=True` and run the training script again (if you wish to save only the weights and not the whole model at all. Either, there is still a better way to achieve that: you can load the model using `load_model` then save the weights using `save_weights` and finally remove the model file).